# How to solve NonNull annotation after Android Studio 3.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint, android-studio-3.2

After updating to Android Studio 3.2, I've been getting a "Probable bugs" from lint saying:

```
"Not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNull".
```

I had no issue before updating to Android Studio 3.2, how do I solve this?

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gallery_view_row, parent, false);
        holder.imageView = row.findViewById(R.id.filePath);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    String file_path = objects.get(position);
    GlideApp.with(context).load(MovieDB.IMAGE_URL + context.getResources().getString(R.string.galleryImgSize) + file_path)
            .into(holder.imageView);
    return row;
}
```

Android Lint never flagged this method before Android Studio 3.2 update, but now I get 2 flags on the method and on the "parent" parameter

Here are the 2 imports used

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

The problem only exists the the "ArrayAdapter" class, the superclass has those 5 imports highlighted in red

```
import android.annotation.ArrayRes;
import android.annotation.IdRes;
import android.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having this same problem, finally discovered a fix, hope it works for you...

Open Settings, select "Editor", then "Inspections".

In the list of inspections, go to "Probable Bugs" and then "@NotNull/@Nullable problems".

On the right pane, select the "CONFIGURE ANNOTATIONS" button.

Add "androidx.annotation.Nullable" and "androidx.annotation.NonNull" to the respective lists.  I also made them the default.

No longer seeing this maddening behavior.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Any method parameter where this warning appears, annotate it with @NonNull. Any method that you're overriding where this appears, do the same (on the line either over or under @Override).

Comment: I already have annotated @NonNull to the methods and parameters, it's just that Android Lint is flagging these methods after 3.2 update. What's the problem in the update?

Answer (score 0):

Add the @NonNull annotation to your method:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public void myOverridenMethod() {
    //your code
}
```

Or just ignore it.

Comment: @NonNull already exists in all the methods that Android Lint is flagging.

Comment: Your override methods do? Can you edit your question with a method that does?

Answer (score 0):

> "Not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNull".

It's pretty clear.

You probably should remove one of those `@NonNull` from the method (OR maybe those who are already added in the method and just making the method `@NonNull`), So:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

This will tell that the `getView` can't be `null` with any of those parameters inside.

Comment: It doesn't work. Could it be related to the migration to AndroidX?

Comment: That's just a lint warning. So, if no errors-crashes comes out, there would be no problem with my provided codes. However, I'd prefer using `Kotlin` with the new AndroidX. You can Also try adding `@NonNull` to the parameters and remove the `@NonNull` of the method and then checking to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate caches and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Check if you import this annotation from the correct package.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem because my android gradle tools too old(2.x) just upgrade project android gradle tools to 3.x solve this.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```